# Old cartoon about gremlins that fly with their ears and want to put a star on a Christmas tree

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I think I watched this cartoon around 2007 or 2008 but I think it's from the 90s/80s. It was about some green gremlins, or something like that, they were flying with their ears. They lived in the woods; it's a Christmas cartoon. One of them wanted to put a star on the top of the Christmas tree but she couldn't fly so she ran away and found some kind of ice queen. The main character had a pink bow.

Comment: I've [edit]ed this post to have a better title. Could you also take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/58193) and [edit] in anything else? For example, you say old, when was that? Do you remember any more plot points?

Comment: I think I watched around 2007 or 2008 and I just rememberd that the maim character had a pink bow, hope it helps

Comment: I've added these details into the question for you. Note that in the future you can [edit] them in yourself.

Comment: when you say 'old cartoon' - how old? You say you watched it in 2007/8 but the cartoon could have been from the 30s. That sort of detail would help

Comment: I'm also looking for this cartoon but I can't find it anywhere... I remember that her friends went looking for her in some kind of a vehicle and they went up the mountain with it